# Blender Python object api: Type method return Enum of string not int as expected

Tags: python, api, blender

I understand what an Enum in C is.
Now I am writing a Blender addon in Python.

This documentation in the `type` method
https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78/bpy.types.Object.html
tells it is returning an `Enum` type.

But the `enum` type is `str`, a string, where is the `int` (I mean numeric) value? Or maybe it is the way Python see those things?

If this is right the documentation must say "return a string" instead of enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it appears to be a blender oddity, by definition an [enumerated type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type) is a set of named values, in C/C++ those values are stored as an int data type, which was probably a decision based on memory usage and performance when comparing them, consider the speed and memory available in 1972 when C was created. The python 3.x standard library has [support for enums](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/enum.html) similar to what you would expect.

So while the object type is an enumeration of possible values, the selected value is stored as a string that is used to correspond to a collection of values defined in the C source.

Part of blenders build process generates the source used to save/load a blend file and is also used to make the python bindings, the related enum in blenders C source can be found [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_object.c;2ca1f297486804dcdb90c376e68dce656a73c726$136), the string located in the second item appears to be the one used for a match in python. If interested [start here](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Architecture/DefineProperty) for an explanation of blenders DNA/RNA.

You can find similar uses in blenders python, the example code [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#get-set-example) shows using a [`bpy.props.EnumProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty) where each enum item is a set of several values. A better example may be using an enum to define a menu, like shown in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46528/935).

A similar oddity is the return type of [operators](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.html), which is a set and each item in the set is a string. We don't just return a string, it needs to be a set of one item that is a string object.

Comment: As you said, python has an enumeration type, I know the developers used some kind of enumeration using a struct in the C file...But doenst matter, in python the method returns a string, not a eNum, thats confuse the user. Anyway thanks for your answer, I used dict to solve this problem.